# O que significa "berenguendém"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Às vezes no site Stack Overflow aparece a publicidade "No SOpt só não tem berenguendém".

[image: publicidade "No SOpt só não tem berenguendém"]

O que significa berenguendém no contexto?

A minha pesquisa sugere ser uma variação de barangandã o que eu também nunca ouvi falar de.

Comment: Tanto a publicidade como a pergunta são muito boas. LOL :)

Comment: *Balangadã* com L, não "barangadã".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Berenguendém, ou Balangandã, é um pequeno acessório de metal muito comum nas roupas das Baianas, sendo a Carmem Miranda (a mulher da foto) a maior representação da Baianas.

a expressão "No SOpt só não tem berenguendém" se refere a [musica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v9JK3ecvmc) da própria Carmem Miranda, mostrando que no SOpt você encontra de tudo, menos berenguendém!

[image: berenguendém]

Isso é um berenguendém

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: A música da Carmem Miranda que fala que só lhe faltam berenguendéns se Chama "South American Way", e faz parte da trilha sonora de Radio Days do Woody Allen.
https://youtu.be/RioDWjtMWIA?si=_idrHNm1P8SZ66ue